# BCD to Excess 3 verilog code (case)

Tags: verilog

I got my code to work. I did not set my output to 3'b000 before running the case statements.  it compiles and gives me desired outputs i think still verifying . I still have trouble with rtl compiler to take a shapshot of the circuit. Im sure every compiler is slightly diffrent so im not sure if anyone can help with this. I'm not sure why it hates everything. will re-post when done or if someones interested in helping thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things that I see are that you need to use semicolon, not comma, to separate your statements.

Also, if you want to set the value of `X` during procedural statement (always block), then it needs to be a `reg` type. Signals declared as output are implicitly `wire` type, unless you declare it as `output reg [3:0] X`.